# Comparing input values

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i'm trying to compare two input values which will alert whenever the second input value is greater than the first. I am a newbie and I do not know what's missing from my code.

Here is my code:

```js
function compute() {
  var fistInput = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var secondInput = document.getElementById("second").value;


  if (firstInput < secondInput) {
    alert("Actual output is greater than expected");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>


</head>

<body>

  First Input:
  <input type="number" value="9" id="first" onchange="compute()">
  <br>Second Output:
  <input type="number" id="second" onchange="compute()">
  <br>


</body>

</html>
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: When you read values from document, they are read as string. Parse them to int and you should be good to go

Comment: Your [tag:java] question tag has been removed as I don't see  how this question has anything to do with programming in the Java language. Please understand that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: sorry for the java tag

Comment: Also there is a typo in `var fistInput = document.getElementById("first").value;`

Comment: you made a typo in variable declaration: `var fistInput` i think it should be `firstInput `

Comment: My code is now working! Big thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You mean `firstInput`, not `fistInput`.

And you must parse your input:

```
var firstInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The values from the input field are read as strings. use `parseInt()` to parse them to integers.

```js
function compute(){
  var fistInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
  var secondInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);


  if(fistInput < secondInput)
  {
      alert("Actual output is greater than expected");
  }
}
```

```html
 

First Input: <input type = "number" value = "9" id = "first" onchange = "compute()"><br>
Second Output: <input type = "number" id = "second" onchange = "compute()"><br>
```

Comment: Adding rectified code is not good enough. Please explain what has been changed. Also You should not answer a typo mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your help!